# Cannot load jQuery because it violates Content Security Policy

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, content-security-policy

I wrote a server on node + express. Prepared the page for rendering, wrote scripts in JS using Jquery. But Jquery can't load the page for some reason. This is a constant case, before I wrote the ToDo application on WebSockets and I had the same error. What is the problem and how to solve it? Help please.
Error:
Refused to load the script 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.

I tried adding different meta tags from other sources, but it didn't help.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Are you using jQuery in the backend or in the frontend?

Comment: it looks like you have the wrong configuration for the CSP header, which doesn't allow to load jquery from third party domains

Comment: Back-end: node.js + express
Front-end: jQuery
on the back side I just render the page

Comment: I'd guess you're using Helmet 4, which sets stricter default rules than it used to, see e.g. https://github.com/textbook/starter-kit/wiki/Content-Security-Policy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one of the better error messages in that it's fairly specific: You've set the [Content Security Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP) for the page to `script-src: 'self'`. The [`script-src`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/script-src) policy controls what sources are valid sources for JavaScript, and `self` means that only sources that are the same origin as the document itself are valid.

You can fix this in one of three ways:

1. Modify the `Content-Security-Policy` header being returned with the page to not include `script-src: self`, or
2. Modify the `Content-Security-Policy` header adding `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com` as as valid source (the list is space-separated), like this:

   `Content-Security-Policy: 'self' https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com`

   or
3. Use a local copy of jQuery served from the same origin as the page

Comment: @t-j-crowder   i am still getting error like mentiond in gist https://gist.github.com/matt212/a92fb309293d7843a82d9e8b47b1f88c

Answer (score 3):

[Content Security Policy](https://content-security-policy.com) is a fairly big topic and it made me stumble for a while.

I ended up using [helmet](https://github.com/helmetjs/helmet), which includes the ability to define settings for Content Security Policy, like this:

```js
app.use(
    helmet({
        contentSecurityPolicy: {
            directives: {
                defaultSrc: ["'self'"],
                scriptSrc: ["'self'", "https://maps.googleapis.com", "https://www.google.com", "https://www.gstatic.com"],
                connectSrc: ["'self'", "https://some-domain.com", "https://some.other.domain.com"],
                styleSrc: ["'self'", "fonts.googleapis.com", "'unsafe-inline'"],
                fontSrc: ["'self'", "fonts.gstatic.com"],
                imgSrc: ["'self'", "https://maps.gstatic.com", "https://maps.googleapis.com", "data:", "https://another-domain.com"],
                frameSrc: ["'self'", "https://www.google.com"]
            }
        },
    })
);
```

I found the ability to define rules using this syntax was easier for me and helped me understand Content Security Policy more.

[Helmet](https://github.com/helmetjs/helmet) is mentioned in the [express.js security docs](https://expressjs.com/en/advanced/best-practice-security.html) and this [node best practises blog](https://medium.com/@nodepractices/were-under-attack-23-node-js-security-best-practices-e33c146cb87d).

Further context for my particular situation, is documented in an answer [I posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64048386).